# Ruby: How to find difference between 2 arrays, order matters

Tags: arrays, ruby, array-difference

I'm trying to count the differences between two arrays where the order DOES matter. For example:

```
array_one = ["A", "B", "C"]
array_two = ["B", "C", "A"]
```

This would yield 3 differences because:

```
array_one[0] != array_two[0]
array_one[1] != array_two[1]
array_one[2] != array_two[2]
```

Another example:

```
array_one = ["Z", "X", "Y"]
array_two = ["Z", "W", "Y"]
```

This would yield 1 because:

```
array_one[0] == array_two[0]
array_one[1] != array_two[1]
array_one[2] == array_two[2]
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about this

```
array_one = ["A", "B", "C"]
array_two = ["A", "C", "A"]

array_one.select.each_with_index { |item, index| 
  array_two[index] != item 
} => #B and C
```

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of methods that uses .select lately. How do you find these combinations? The docs doesn't really show what happens when you plug `.select.each_with_index`

Comment: @KaMok, Yeah, documentation shows only the part related to the particular function or method. E.g in this case, if you see the [ruby array select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) docs, you will see the select returns an `Enumerator`.  and [Enumerator docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html) show what are the methods that can be used with them :). Its little hard at first, but with time you'll get used to know how a method can be chained with another. reading docs will help you to improve this..

Answer (score 4):

You can merge the two arrays using `zip`, and count the inside array where the two values are equal.

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [1,5,6]

arr1.zip(arr2)             #=> [[1, 1], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
    .count {|a, b| a == b} #=> 1
```

Another way is the just iterate through both array and run a counter

```
count = 0

(0...arr1.length).each do |idx|
  count += 1 if arr1[idx] == arr2[idx]
end
```

Of course, both assume the two arrays are the same length.

`(0...arr1.length)` is the same as `0 to arr1.length-1`, the `...` is exclusive.

Comment: Depending on the ruby version you can use #each_with_index http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index

Comment: i thought about that, i'm not a fan of `each_with_index` in this case, because I will have something like  `arr1_val == arr2[idx]` inside the block, I did it my way for the sake of uniformity.

Answer (score 2):

Just because I like stuff like this, I benchmarked the solutions, just wanted to share in case anyone is interested (I just switched the array to a bigger one to get more meaningful results)

```
require "benchmark/ips"

def method_1(ar_1, ar_2)
  ar = ar_1.zip ar_2

  ar.count { |els| els[0] == els[1]  }
end

def method_2(ar_1, ar_2)
  count = 0
  ar_1.each_with_index { |el, i| count += 1 if el == ar_2[i] }
end

def method_3(ar_1, ar_2)
  count = 0

  (0...ar_1.length).each do |idx|
    count += 1 if ar_1[idx] == ar_2[idx]
  end
end

def method_4(ar_1, ar_2)
  ar_1.zip(ar_2).inject(0) do |memo, (left, right)|
    if left == right
      memo
    else
      memo + 1
    end
  end
end

def method_5(ar_1, ar_2)
  ar_1.select.each_with_index do |item, index|
    ar_2[index] != item
  end
end

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  # ar_1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
  # ar_2 = ["B", "C", "A"]

  ar_1 = (0..1_000_000).to_a.shuffle
  ar_2 = (0..1_000_000).to_a.shuffle

  x.report("zip and count") do |times|
    i = 0
    while i < times
      method_1 ar_1, ar_2
      i += 1
    end
  end

  x.report("each with index") do |times|
    i = 0
    while i < times
      method_2 ar_1, ar_2
      i += 1
    end
  end

  x.report("0..length each") do |times|
    i = 0
    while i < times
      method_3 ar_1, ar_2
      i += 1
    end
  end

  x.report("zip and inject") do |times|
    i = 0
    while i < times
      method_4 ar_1, ar_2
      i += 1
    end
  end

  x.report("select each with index") do |times|
    i = 0
    while i < times
      method_5 ar_1, ar_2
      i += 1
    end
  end

  x.compare!
end

###################################################
# 10_000 elements per array                       #
###################################################
#
# Warming up --------------------------------------
#        zip and count    54.000  i/100ms
#      each with index    92.000  i/100ms
#       0..length each    87.000  i/100ms
#       zip and inject    41.000  i/100ms
# select each with index
#                         82.000  i/100ms
# Calculating -------------------------------------
#        zip and count    545.700  (± 2.6%) i/s -      2.754k in   5.050362s
#      each with index    919.259  (± 3.0%) i/s -      4.600k in   5.008972s
#       0..length each    919.908  (± 1.4%) i/s -      4.611k in   5.013518s
#       zip and inject    413.470  (± 1.7%) i/s -      2.091k in   5.058865s
# select each with index
#                         828.774  (± 3.5%) i/s -      4.182k in   5.053036s
#
# Comparison:
#       0..length each:      919.9 i/s
#      each with index:      919.3 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
# select each with index:      828.8 i/s - 1.11x slower
#        zip and count:      545.7 i/s - 1.69x slower
#       zip and inject:      413.5 i/s - 2.22x slower


###################################################
# 1_000_000 elements per array                       #
###################################################
#
# Warming up --------------------------------------
#        zip and count     1.000  i/100ms
#      each with index     1.000  i/100ms
#       0..length each     1.000  i/100ms
#       zip and inject     1.000  i/100ms
# select each with index
#                          1.000  i/100ms
# Calculating -------------------------------------
#        zip and count      5.447  (±18.4%) i/s -     26.000  in   5.088342s
#      each with index      9.292  (± 0.0%) i/s -     47.000  in   5.058805s
#       0..length each      9.104  (± 0.0%) i/s -     46.000  in   5.053701s
#       zip and inject      3.983  (± 0.0%) i/s -     20.000  in   5.042810s
# select each with index
#                           7.777  (±12.9%) i/s -     39.000  in   5.053795s
#
# Comparison:
#      each with index:        9.3 i/s
#       0..length each:        9.1 i/s - 1.02x slower
# select each with index:        7.8 i/s - 1.19x slower
#        zip and count:        5.4 i/s - 1.71x slower
#       zip and inject:        4.0 i/s - 2.33x slower
```

Answer (score 1):

@davidhu2000 beat me to it, but as this approach *is* slightly different, it might still be worth mentioning:

```
array_one = ["A", "B", "C"]
array_two = ["B", "C", "A"]

array_one.zip(array_two).inject(0) { |memo, (left, right)|
  unless left == right
    memo + 1
  else
    memo
  end
} # => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this

```
array_one = ["A", "B", "C"]
array_two = ["A", "C", "A"]

array_one.select.each_with_index { |item, index| 
  array_two[index] != item 
} => #["B", "C"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_one = ["A", "B", "C"]
array_two = ["A", "C", "A"]

enum_two = array_two.to_enum
array_one.select { |s| s != enum_two.next }
  #=> ["B", "C"]
```